# Return true and setimout

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this function return `true`?

```
function test(str) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if(str == 'ok') {
            return true;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

console.log(test('ok'));
```

---

That's not exactly what i want to do.
I have a function nammed test() who does some actions after 1 second.
I want to execute next function, when test() is finished (so after the timeout).

How i can know when test i finished ?

Comment: What is the purpose of calling setTimeout like this?

Comment: I want to do some actions, and after a time, i want to know when this function is finished

Comment: You are on the wrong track. Cos set timeout will call the function in a different scope. Can i know if you have any function to call after the setTimeout function is finished and I can help you.

Comment: Test is finished long before the setTimeout is executed. To know when something is finished, use callbacks as described in the answers.

Answer (score 9):

Tracing your code, here's what happens.

1. `test()` is invoked.
2. `setTimeout` schedules a function to be called 1000 ms later.
3. `test()` concludes execution, no `return` statement was executed, so `undefined` is returned instead.
4. about 1000 ms later the scheduled function fires.
5. The scheduled function returns `true` to nothing.

In other words, it just doesn't work that way. The JS interpreter does not pause, it continues over the timeout.  You cannot pause execution in JS.

---

Instead you typically use callbacks:

```
function test(str, callback) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (str === 'ok') {
      callback(true);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

// logs 'true' 1000 ms later
test('ok', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});

// logs nothing, callback never fires
test('NOTOK!', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

This code will do more what you seem to have expected.

Answer (score 6):

It does not return `true` because the `setTimeout` call is asynchronous. Also, the return value `true` in your code comes from an inner function.

The normal way of handling such program flow is to pass a callback to the asynchronous function.

```js
function test(str, callback) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        callback(str == 'ok');
    }, 1000);
}

test('ok', function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The function passed as the second argument to `test()` will be called when `setTimeout` executes the code. The argument to the callback function will tell if `str` is was `ok` or not.

Comment: So how to do, to `return true` or `false` ?
I want to know when this function is finished :)

Comment: @dragon75: I think that depends on what you are trying to do. Currently I think its unclear what the function is using the `setTimeout` for. If you just want the test function to return true then take the timeout code out.

Comment: You know that the function has finished because the callback executes! So put whatever code you need to follow in the callback.

Comment: The `callback` parameter to the anonymous function shadows the parameter to the `test` function that you actually want.

Comment: @dragon75: `setTimeout(function(){ callback(str == 'ok'); },1000)`

Answer (score 4):

For starters, settimeout is an asynchronous method, so the actual function test() will have finished and returned before the settimout code runs.

Secondly however, you are only returning true from the settimeout function not the test function, so you will never get anything other than false.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return true because asynchronous function setTimeout() will execute after 1000 ms and console.log will execute in normal fashion without waiting of your 'test' function.